# How do I resize a gridsplitters height so it doesn't cut off my menu and toolbar at the top of my wpf app?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two grid rows at the top of my wpf app. A menu and a toolbar. When I use a gridsplitter it cuts off both the menu and toolbar. I want to adjust the height of the gridsplitter so it takes into account the height of both grid rows and sets just below the toolbar. How can I do this? Here's my code and a picture of the problem.

[image: My app with the menu and toolbar cut off because of the gridsplitter settings.]

```xml
<Window x:Class="M4aToMP3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:M4aToMP3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="M4aToMP3" Height="600" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Grid Name="gridMain" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="240"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <GridSplitter Name="gridSplitterMain" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="5"/>
        
        <Menu Name="menuMain" Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem Header="_File"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_View"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help"></MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="1">
            <ToolBar Name="toolBarMain" Height="40">
                <Button>
                    <Image Source="icons8-audio-file-32.png"></Image>
                </Button>
                <Button>
                    <Image Source="icons8-music-folder-32.png"></Image>
                </Button>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I read many articles on the gridsplitter control and tried many different settings but I havn't found a solution.

Comment: Use a dockpanel to dock the menu and toolbar at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to not deal with the `Menu` or the `ToolBarTray` at all. Organize them with a `DockPanel` or in an outer `Grid`.

Here is an example using a `DockPanel`

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit" />
            <MenuItem Header="_View" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Help" />
        </Menu>
        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ToolBar Height="40">
                <Button>
                    <Image Source="icons8-audio-file-32.png" />
                </Button>
                <Button>
                    <Image Source="icons8-music-folder-32.png" />
                </Button>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="240" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                          Width="5"
                          ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Now the `GridSplitter` affects only the grid colums it should.

Comment: Thanks so much Sir Rufo for the solution. It's now working like it should!

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use DockPanel in this way

```
<DockPanel>
    <Grid Name="gridMain" ShowGridLines="True" 
          DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="22"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="240"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <GridSplitter Name="gridSplitterMain" Grid.Column="1" 
                      Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="5"/>

        <Menu Name="menuMain" Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem Header="_File"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_View"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help"></MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="1">
            <ToolBar Name="toolBarMain" Height="40">
                <Button>
                    <Image Source="icons8-audio-file-32.png"></Image>
                </Button>
                <Button>
                    <Image Source="icons8-music-folder-32.png"></Image>
                </Button>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>

    </Grid>
    <Grid Name="gridContent">

    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: The OP want to split the area below menu and toolbar